# How can I get a value from a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

I have a `map` named `valueMap` as follows:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string>MAP;
MAP valueMap;
...
// Entering data.
```

Then I am passing this map to a function by reference:

```
void function(const MAP &map)
{
  std::string value = map["string"];
  // By doing so I am getting an error.
}
```

How can I get the value from the map, which is passed as a reference to a function?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` is a non-const member function, and you have a const reference.

You either need to change the signature of `function` or do:

```
MAP::const_iterator pos = map.find("string");
if (pos == map.end()) {
    //handle the error
} else {
    std::string value = pos->second;
    ...
}
```

`operator[]` handles the error by adding a default-constructed value to the map and returning a reference to it. This is no use when all you have is a const reference, so you will need to do something different.

You *could* ignore the possibility and write `string value = map.find("string")->second;`, if your program logic somehow guarantees that `"string"` is already a key. The obvious problem is that if you're wrong then you get undefined behavior.

Comment: use `MAP::const_iterator` intead of `auto` if your compiler does not support `auto` yet.

Comment: shouldnt it be `std::string value = pos->second;` or `const std::string& value = pos->second;`?

Comment: @smerlin: good point, fixed. Whether the questioner actually needs a copy of the value, or could use a const reference, depends on code not shown. So I decided not to bother with it :-)

Answer (score 36):

`map.at("key")` throws exception if missing key.

> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the
> function throws an out_of_range exception.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that `operator[]` is used to insert and read a value into and from the map, so it cannot be const.
If the key does not exist, it will create a new entry with a default value in it, incrementing the size of the map, that will contain a new key with an empty string ,in this particular case, as a value if the key does not exist yet.
You should avoid `operator[]` when reading from a map and use, as was mention before, `map.at(key)` to ensure bound checking. This is one of the most common mistakes people often do with maps. You should use `insert` and `at` unless your code is aware of this fact. Check this talk about common bugs [Curiously Recurring C++ Bugs at Facebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkgszkPnV8g&t=1081s)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699752/2675154) by *Steve Jessop* explains well, why you can't use `std::map::operator[]` on a `const std::map`. *Gabe Rainbow's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21085734/2675154) suggests a nice alternative. I'd just like to provide some example code on how to use [`map::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/). So, here is an enhanced example of your `function()`:

```
void function(const MAP &map, const std::string &findMe) {
    try {
        const std::string& value = map.at(findMe);
        std::cout << "Value of key \"" << findMe.c_str() << "\": " << value.c_str() << std::endl;
        // TODO: Handle the element found.
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        std::cout << "Key \"" << findMe.c_str() << "\" not found" << std::endl;
        // TODO: Deal with the missing element.
    }
}
```

And here is an example `main()` function:

```
int main() {
    MAP valueMap;
    valueMap["string"] = "abc";
    function(valueMap, "string");
    function(valueMap, "strong");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Value of key "string": abc
>   Key "strong" not found

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/VDvdag)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the value from the map, which is passed as a reference to a function?

Well, you can pass it as a reference. [The standard reference wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) that is.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MAP;
// create your map reference type
using map_ref_t = std::reference_wrapper<MAP>;

// use it 
void function(map_ref_t map_r)
{
    // get to the map from inside the
    // std::reference_wrapper
    // see the alternatives behind that link
    MAP & the_map = map_r;
    // take the value from the map
    // by reference
    auto & value_r = the_map["key"];
    // change it, "in place"
    value_r = "new!";
}
```

And the test.

```
    void test_ref_to_map() {

    MAP valueMap;
    valueMap["key"] = "value";
    // pass it by reference
    function(valueMap);
    // check that the value has changed
    assert( "new!" == valueMap["key"] );
}
```

I think this is nice and simple. Enjoy ...

Answer (score 0):

Although it's kinda late but I am still gonna answer, thanks to previous answers on this question i was able to forge this class which reuse pointers and values, it creates two maps to store data, Here the code if anybody interested..

```
template<class T1, class T2> class Bimap
{
std::map<T1, T2*> map1;
std::map<T2, T1*> map2;
public:
    void addRow(T1 &t1, T2 &t2){
        map1.insert(make_pair(t1, &t2));
        map2.insert(make_pair(t2, &t1));
    }
    T2* findForward(T1 t1){
        T2* value = map1.find(t1)->second;
        return value;
    }
    T1* findBackward(T2 t2){
        T1* value = map2.find(t2)->first;
        return value;
    }
};
```

Using class:

```
//Init mapp with int,int
Bimap<int,int> mapp;

//Add a row(Record) in bimap
int a = 5;
int b = 7002;
mapp.addRow(a, b);

//Print a record
int *ans= mapp.findForward(a);
cout<<"Bimap Returned:"<<*ans<<endl;
```