# How to get element from const map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, stl, constants

I have some struct like bellow to get static const map:

```
struct SupportedPorts{
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> init()
        {
          std::map<std::string, std::string> port;
          port["COM1"] = "ttySO1";
          port["COM2"] = "ttySO2";
          port["USB"]  = "ttyUSB0";
          return port;
        }
    static const std::map<std::string, std::string> supported_ports;
};
```

But I have problem when I trying get some value by key. In cpp file of class Exmaple:

```
#include "Example.h"

const std::map<std::string, std::string> SupportedPorts::supported_ports = SupportedPorts::init();

Example::Example(){
   std::cout << SupportedPorts::supported_ports['COM1'];
}
```

I get error like bellow:

```
note: initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());
error: conversion to non-const reference type ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::key_type&& {aka class std::basic_string<char>&&}’ from rvalue of type ‘std::basic_string<char>’ [-fpermissive]
     std::cout << SupportedPorts::supported_ports['COM1'];
                                                         ^
(null):0: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Comment: I see you have just learned that `[]` edits the map

Comment: Or this: [How can I get a value from a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699689/how-can-i-get-a-value-from-a-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator [] is declared for the class template std::map the following way

```
T& operator[](const key_type& x);
T& operator[](key_type&& x);
```

That is the  the operator returns a non-constant reference that may not be done for a constant object. And the operator may be called only for a non-constant object because it is declared without the qualifier `const`.

Instead use the function `at` declared like

```
T& at(const key_type& x);
const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
```

Also instead of a string literal you are using a multibyte character literal in this statement

```
 std::cout << SupportedPorts::supported_ports['COM1'];
```

Write

```
 std::cout << SupportedPorts::supported_ports.at( "COM1" );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    const std::map<std::string, std::string> supported_ports =
    {
        { "COM1",  "ttySO1" }, { "COM2", "ttySO2" }, { "USB", "ttyUSB0" }
    };
    
    std::cout << supported_ports.at( "COM1" ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ttySO1
```

Comment: the crucial point is that `[]` potentially inserts an element into the map. A `const T& operator[] const` could not do that